# Not able to parse data to a class in Java

Tags: java, class, oop

I am trying to learn object oriented code in Java, and am following a tutorial. I am currently stuck trying to parse a string into my class. It is returning the following error:

```
Name cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have a main file, called `start.java`, and the class I am trying to call is in a different file, called `phone.java`. Both are in a folder called src. Below is the start.java code (which is throwing the error)

```
package src;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        phone android = new phone(Name:"android 10");
        System.out.println(android.getName());
    }
}
```

And here is the class I am trying to call, in phone.java

```
package src;

public class phone{
    private String name;

    public phone(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Much thanks for your help

Comment: What is (Name:"android 10")?   Get rid of Name:   Also classes should start with an uppercase.

Comment: Yes a ":" isn't Java syntax.  You just pass the argument `new phone( "android 10" );`.  Java doesn't have named variables for argument passing so trying to pass in `Name:` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `Name` from `new phone(Name:"android 10")` and need to use `new phone("android 10")`.
You just need to pass the value for the name, your constructor will bind it to the name variable.

Refer below code

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        phone android = new phone("android 10");
        System.out.println(android.getName());
    }
}
```